# UIDatePicker: Minimum Date

Tags: ios, uidatepicker, datetime-format

I would like to show only time in UIDatePicker with minimumTime +12 Hours.  Below is my code:

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{
    NSLog(@"startTimeLabel %@", startTimeLabel);
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];
    NSDate *minimumTime = [formatter dateFromString:startTimeLabel];
    NSLog(@"minimumTime Formatted %@", minimumTime);


    UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[[UIDatePicker alloc] init] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 216)];

    pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    [pickerView setMinimumDate:minimumTime];

    [pickerView setMinuteInterval:15];
    [pickerView setTag: kDatePickerTag1];
    //Add picker to action sheet
    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
    NSArray *subviews = [actionSheet subviews];
}
```

Here is the log:

```
2013-07-17 18:13:37.682 MeetingTime[12294:c07] startTimeLabel 6:15 PM
2013-07-17 18:13:37.683 MeetingTime[12294:c07] minimumTime Formatted 2000-01-01 20:15:00 +0000
```

Q1.  Why is startTimeLabel showing up as 6:15 PM but after format it's 20:15:00+0000.  Shouldn't it be 18:15 ?   Is my format wrong?  I don't need the date, can I get rid of it?

Q2.  I'd like the picker to get the minimum time from startTimeLabel and use it as the minimumTime.  Is it possible to not show any time before the minimum time?  i.e. if startTimeLabel is 6:15 PM then the only options in the UIPicker will be 6:30PM + 12 Hours ?  How can I accomplish this?  Thanks.

Comment: Q1. what is your Time Zone ?

Comment: We're in U.S. pacific standard time (PST).  But I would like to app to work in any time zone.

Answer (score 0):

For Q1, it has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442706/nsdateformatter-and-time-zone-issue).

For Q2, you can evaluate the value of `startTimeLabel` and add 12 hours to it, then set it as minimum date for `UIDatePicker` by `setMinimumDate` method.

Comment: Thanks.  For Q2:  If setMinimumDate time is 4:00PM, can UIPicker only display Time 4:00pm and after?  I'm trying to do that with the code above, however, UIPicker is showing full 24-hours.  Basically, I don't want UIPicker to display any time before the minimumDate.

Comment: you probably have to do extra check when user selects a date / time.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you.  I have the user select a time, I store in a variable startTimeVariable.  Then I convert it to NSDate format and store it in minimumDate variable.  Again, the question is can I make it where UIPicker does not display time before what is stored in minimumDate? If the user selected 4:00PM, UIPicker will only show time after 4:00PM.  If yes, what is the code?  The code that I have above is NOT working.  Thanks.